# Looping through Laravel validation errors dynamic object in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, laravel

I have a validator inside a Laravel controller and have a dynamic object created by using ReactJS. The problem is, I have a problem on displaying the dynamic error, such as the example below, listedItems.0.itemName or listedItems.1.itemName. If it's not dynamic, I am able to display it by using this particular code. But if I tried doing the dynamic workaround, it won't appear on my page. How should I amend the code for it to display the dynamic object errors? Thank you.

**Code Workaround**

```
Not Dynamic
{(typeof errors.isDeclared!== 'undefined') ? <p style={{ color:'red' }}>* {errors.isDeclared}</p> : null}

Dynamic Workaround
{(typeof errors.listedItems !== 'undefined') ? <p style={{ color:'red' }}>* {errors.listedItems[0]}</p> : null}
```

**Error Message**

```
errors:
  borrowPurpose: ['The borrow purpose field is required.']
  isDeclared: ['The is declared field is required.']
  listedItems.0.itemName: ['The item name field is required.']
  listedItems.0.itemRemark: ['The item remark field is required.']
```

Code

```
return (
                 <div className="bg-white overflow-hidden shadow-sm sm:rounded-lg mb-2">
                    <div className="p-6 bg-white border-b border-gray-200">
                        <div>
                            <Row>
                                <Col><h5>Items <span style={{ color:'red' }}>*</span></h5></Col>
                                <Col style={{ textAlign:'right' }}><FormAddItem handleAddItem={handleAddItem} /></Col>
                                {/* <Col style={{ textAlign:'right' }}><Button onClick={() => setValue('listedItems',items)}>Update</Button></Col> */}
                            </Row>
                        </div>
                        {/* <hr /> */}
                        <input type="text" name="listedItems" {...register('listedItems')} hidden />
                        <ItemsList data={items} removeItem={removeItem}/>
                        {(typeof errors.listedItems !== 'undefined') ? <p style={{ color:'red' }}>* {errors.listedItems[0]}</p> : null}
                    </div>
                </div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over `listedItems` in your React component's render function to dynamically display however many validation errors are returned by Laravel:

```js
render = () => {

    // The rest of your render code here

    let errorList = [];
    listedItems.forEach((listedIte) => {
        errorList.push(<p style={{ color:'red' }}>* {errors.listedItems[0]}</p>)
    })
    
    return (
        <div>
            {errorList}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the reply, sir. But may I know in specific, if this can be applied to the ReactJS functional component? I cannot see how can I amend it to fit on a functional component in ReactJS. I have updated some part of my code to the question as well.